# QuantLib : building discount_curve from spots

Tags: python, quantlib

I have just started using QuantLib and getting my head around various features. The question is I have a hypothetical spot curve shown below

spot_tenors = [0.0,
 0.5,
 1.0,
 1.5,
 2.0,
 2.5,
 3.0,
 3.5,
 4.0,
 4.5,
 5.0,
 5.5,
 6.0,
 6.5,
 7.0,
 7.5,
 8.0,
 8.5,
 9.0,
 9.5,
 10.0]

spots = 
[0.0,
 5.25,
 5.43,
 5.76,
 6.02,
 6.28,
 6.55,
 6.82,
 6.87,
 7.1,
 7.21,
 7.26,
 7.31,
 7.43,
 7.48,
 7.54,
 7.67,
 7.8,
 7.79,
 7.93,
 8.07]

when I try and create discount_curve and discount_handle I am getting errors as many of my tenors are floats 1.5,2.5 and so on

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('macosx')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import QuantLib as ql

#create a bond
issueDate = ql.Date(15, 1, 2015)
maturityDate = ql.Date(15, 1, 2025)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
businessConvention = ql.Unadjusted
dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
monthEnd = False
schedule = ql.Schedule (issueDate, maturityDate, tenor, calendar, businessConvention, businessConvention, dateGeneration, monthEnd)

# Now lets build the coupon
dayCount = ql.Thirty360()
couponRate = .06
coupons = [couponRate]

settlementDays = 0
faceValue = 100
bond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, faceValue, schedule, coupons, dayCount)

today = ql.Date(30, ql.January, 2020)
nodes = [today + Period(n, Years) for n in spot_tenors] #this is where I get the error

discount_curve = ql.ZeroCurve(nodes, spots, ql.Actual360())
discount_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(discount_curve)
bond.setPricingEngine(ql.DiscountingBondEngine(discount_handle))
```

the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prasadkamath/anaconda2/envs/Pk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-301-cc1508b12a56>", line 1, in <module>
    [today + Period(n, Years) for n in tenors]
  File "<ipython-input-301-cc1508b12a56>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    [today + Period(n, Years) for n in tenors]
  File "/Users/prasadkamath/anaconda2/envs/Pk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/QuantLib/QuantLib.py", line 183, in __init__
    _QuantLib.Period_swiginit(self, _QuantLib.new_Period(*args))
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Period'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Period::Period()
    Period::Period(Integer,TimeUnit)
    Period::Period(Frequency)
    Period::Period(std::string const &)
```

any idea how do I fix the problem or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

There must be something missing in the code you posted because it will not produce that error. Your error has to do with the construction of the `Period` object, which should be either:

- `ql.Period('6M')` for a string as the input
- `ql.Period(6, ql.Months)` for an integer as the number of periods and the TimeUnit object

In any case, the way to construct the ZeroCurve would be:

```
dates = [ql.Date(31,12,2019),  ql.Date(31,12,2020),  ql.Date(31,12,2021)]
zeros = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03]
curve = ql.ZeroCurve(dates, zeros, ql.ActualActual(), ql.TARGET())
```

Then you can get the discount factors using either a yearfraction or a date:

```
curve.discount(1.5)
curve.discount(ql.Date(15,6,2021))
```

Comment: thanks a lot David, that was very helpful - appreciate that. What is strange is using the same code if I use non floating values in tenors I get the answer i.e. if I use tenors = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and corresponding spots I dont get the error. So for some reason  the code ```nodes = [today + Period(n, Years) for n in spot_tenors]``` doesnt like floating values for n. Regarding the Period object construction comment I dont see having explicitly constructed that anywhere, again am I missing something?